# Tag for "developing ON Windows"

Tags: discussion, tags

I just had a question related to the use of `npm` on Windows. I tagged it `windows`, however I'm not completely satisfied. The tag's description says:

> Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft. *Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior.* Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Windows are off-topic.

For one, the tag is extremely broad (and broader tags tend to be less useful). But more important, I interpret the tag to mainly mean you are *developing for Windows* (a Windows app, Win32/WPF/UWP). I would put things there that are less specific than e.g. `win32`, but pertaining to Windows application development in general. I don't know, a question about `\\?\C:\\Windows\Paths`.

I am *developing on Windows*, i.e. Windows as a development environment. The question I asked was about React Native, so it has nothing to do with Windows as a platform. But as everybody knows, programming on Windows can sometimes be a bit peculiar compared to unix-like platforms, and one develops special skill set. I would like to have a tag to summon people with this skill set.

What do you think, can we make a tag similar to `development-on-windows`? If such a tag existed, I think I would follow it. Can someone come up with a catchier name?

Questions would be about:

- difficulties when compiling on Windows (e.g. for Android!) compared to other platforms like Linux
- getting compilers and IDEs to work on Windows
- workarounds for missing behaviors (symlinks, fork) in tools and so on.

Of course, this is not meant for *general* Windows troubleshooting, but only for questions that are already on topic here.

Comment: I think [tag:windows] suits well as your question's about "Windows-specific behavior".

Comment: Is that relevant? I'm developing on my laptop, should I use [tag:laptop]? No, for obvious reason. Tags are means to connect experts to questions they are able to answer. Someone might be able to know the answer to your c# question, whenever or not you or him develop on windows, linux, haiku, etc.

Comment: @Braiam: That's not the same. What if your C# question is ultra-specific to Mono on macOS? Then it would make sense to somehow have the tags reflect that, since a WPF developer couldn't answer it. Same in my case. A node developer on macOS could not answer my question, but windows C++ developer might say "Sure, you have to edit that registry key and copy that DLL". These are orthogonal questions.

Comment: Do any programmers still write code on windows though?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use [tag:windows] here.  I would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Without tagging the os, if your question  became void, then you can use the tag Windows.

Otherwise if you are facing a problem in some specific editor, use the editor tag instead.

If it is completely syntactical or similar error, then don't tag is or editor.

The info of [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) as mentioned, I am highlighting the part

---

*Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or **Windows-specific behavior**. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Windows are off-topic.*

Comment: OK, what should I tag if I have an Android project that compiles fine on Linux, but fails on Windows? The reason might be e.g. the case insensitive file system, I don't know that. This is clearly not a Windows app development question, but a distinct problem.

Comment: Read the bold text. Fails on windows is a windows specific behaviour

Comment: How would adding a tag for "development on windows" help with that @jdm? Any more than using the "windows" tag, I mean. Doesn't "windows-specific behaviour" heavily imply "development on windows" anyway?

Comment: @SagarV I know what that description says, in fact I cite it in my question. Did you read the whole question? I am suggesting to clarify this case: I want a new tag meaning "windows-specific behavior of development tools"... General comment: if somebody suggests to extend A with B, you cannot respond with "Read A". I know A, that's why I want also B.

Comment: You have the create tag privilege. So you can create whatever you want but _new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period._

Comment: You can respond with "Read A", if having both "A" and "B" would be redundant

Comment: @Clive: Yes, "windows-specific behavior" implies "development on windows", it also implies "special behavior of `fopen` on windows". It is overloaded. I want to split the first "development on windows" part out into a new tag. I often encounter quirks of windows as an environment (not as a platform), and I want to ask about them, but I also think I could answer those questions. That's why I think such a tag would be useful.

Comment: Maybe it's just the name thing that seems redundant then. I mean, the whole site's about development so "windows" and "development on windows" feel pretty synonymous (to me at least). Perhaps there's a better phrase?

Comment: @jdm if you want to create a tag, then don't forget the criteria I mentioned above

Comment: @Clive: Thing is I can ask a question about Visual Studio as a tool, or Atom as a tool, I just think I should be able to ask about Windows as a tool. Long time ago I had a problem with HTML files encoding, but it happened only when editing on Windows. That kind of question would just drown in the `windows` tag. I don't know what a good phrase would be, naming is hard!

Comment: @SagarV: Maybe I'll create a tag tomorrow. If people find it useful and it catches on, that's great, and if not, also fine, and it will get deleted. I understand people in this thread are rather sceptic, but you are probably not the people who have to fight with developing on Windows :-).